# How to implement the red curvy line that word shows during misspellings using Word API/Office JS?

Tags: javascript, office-js, word-addins, office-js-helpers, scriptlab

I am using ScriptLab to develop a word addin. My current goal is now to underline a word (In some way, I know this word) in red curvy line. This is something that word shows when you make misspelled something or made an error. I was able to do this. (Though I only wanted the underline to be red but the font gets red too). But the problem is when I convert my document to PDF the underline does not go. So, I realized this is not something I want. When I convert the document to PDF, I want the red underline removed (Something that happens automatically in Word).

I can do this manually. But I think there will be too much corner cases and errors. So, it is better to use Word API's feature (if it is available). Currently, I can't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in Word.js to get control of Office's red curvy underline. You can suggest this at [Office Developer Suggestion box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).